# Maximum scale of secondary horizontal X-axis VBA

Tags: vba

By the following code Max. and Min. scale for primary horizontal X-axis of a chart in vba is being set;

```
Sub chart_set()
    Dim objCht As ChartObject
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.Axes(xlValue)
    .MinimumScale = 0
    .MaximumScale = my_max_var
    End With
End Sub
```

is there any way to set the secondary one's as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the code below will `Set objCht` to the ChartObject in `ActiveSheet` (see here recommendation how to stay away from `ActiveSheet` [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros))

The code below will check if a secondary axis is applied, if not it will add it to the chart. Afterwards, it will modify the `MinimumScale` and `MaximumScale` to 20 and 50 (just random numbers I've selected).

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub chart_set()

Dim objCht  As ChartObject
Dim my_max_var As Long

' just for my tests
my_max_var = 1000

' set chart object
Set objCht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)

With objCht
    With .Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
        .MinimumScale = 0
        .MaximumScale = my_max_var
    End With

    ' check if Secondary Axis is applied
    If .Chart.HasAxis(xlValue, xlSecondary) = False Then
        .Chart.HasAxis(xlValue, xlSecondary) = True
    End If

    ' modify minimum and maximum values of seconday axis
    With .Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary)
        .MinimumScale = 20
        .CrossesAt = 20
        .MaximumScale = 50
    End With

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Shai, just what I needed!

Comment: Your'e welcome :) try using next time `Sheets("YourSheetName")` , instead of `ActiveSheet` . it will help you avoide possible errors