# VBA Runtime Error 1004 setting min and max chart axis values

Tags: excel, vba, charts, axis

I have an MS Acces Db.
I have a command button to export (TransferSpreadsheet acExport) a query to Excel and create a Chart (Set ch = ws.Shapes.AddChart.Chart)

This is my code working fine:

```
With ch
  .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
  .SeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2
  .SeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlLineMarkers
  .ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 69
  .Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Delete
  .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = False
  .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = False
  .SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)
End with
```

I need to set a chart's axis maximum and minimum values using vba. I need to refer to chart already in the worksheet.

Any time I add to my code:

```
.MaximumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("Axis_max").Value
.MinimumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("Axis_min").Value
```

VBA displays ERROR 1004 “Application-defined or Object”
I'm confused why my code does not run those instructions

I really would be grateful if someone could give me a steer on this,

All the best

Comment: Can you verify that `ActiveSheet.Range("Axis_max").Value` returns a numeric value? Wouldn't rather pull the value from a _specific_ sheet, like `Sheets("chart_options").Range("Axis_max").Value`

Comment: ja72
I appreciate your reply.

When testing your recommendation when I type: 
ActiveSheet.Range("Axis_max")
VBA displays ERROR 1004 and VBA paints yellow the line of code

On the other hand, when I type
Sheets("chart_options").Range("Axis_max").Value
VBA displays Error 9 and VBA paints yellow the line of code

Comment: Well, you don't have a sheet named "chart_options". I just made up that name as a placeholder for where you would store the axis scaling information. You need to use whatever sheet name you have these values stored at.

Comment: Ja72
When I type instead of ("chart_options"), "Sheet1"
VBA displays Error 1004

When I type instead of ("chart_options"), "qryname"
VBA displays Error 1004

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If this is Access VBA and not Excel VBA, then functions like `ActiveSheet()` or `Sheets()` won't work. Access does not know anything about spreadsheets. You need a reference to the created Excel workbook to make this work.

Comment: I know Access VBA does not know something about spreadsheets. 
Unfortunately, I still don't know how to deal with the reference you indicate.
Please. Could you give me a light?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `.MinimumScale` and `.MaximumScale` are not properties of a `Chart` but of an `Axis` objects.

Try instead:

```
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MaximumScale = Sheet1.Range("Axis_max").Value
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MinimumScale = Sheet1.Range("Axis_min").Value
```

Comment: ja72
I was unable to run your code.
For hours I have been googling an
I found this code here from Shai Rado and I just adapted for me and works fine. 
However, with this code, I have to type minimum and maximum values. 
I need VBA to read those values from Sheet1 (range B2 and range C2) to set the axis chart values also in Sheet1.
Shai Rado link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41414615/maximum-scale-of-secondary-horizontal-x-axis-vba

Comment: So is the problem that you cannot set the scale, or that you cannot read a value. The linked code is identical to my answer, except that instead of hard-coding a value, it is read from `Sheet1`.

Comment: I cannot set the scale with the code. 
I think my problem is that I don't know the code I have to type before:
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MaximumScale = Sheet1.Range("Axis_max").Value
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MinimumScale = Sheet1.Range("Axis_min").Value

Comment: If I record a Macro to insert a chart in the worksheet, how can I use these lines of code:

.MaximumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("Axis_max").Value
.MinimumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("Axis_min").Value

I have been googling with no success.

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a code to set minimum and maximum vertical chart axes.

```
With ch
.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
.SeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2
.SeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlLineMarkers
.ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 69

myMax = DMax("Total_Sal", "qry_task")
myMin = DMin("Total_Sal", "qry_task")

 With .Axes(xlvalue, xlPrimary)
        .MinimumScale = myMin
        .MaximumScale = myMax
 End With

myMax = DMax("Task_Val", "qry_task")
myMin = DMin("Task_Val", "qry_task")
With .Axes(xlvalue, xlSecondary)
        .MinimumScale = myMin
        .MaximumScale = myMax
    End With
```

End with

I really appreciate the initial help from ja72

To complete my code I had help from [Andy Pope](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-pro...ml#post4969801)